# passing form to user control breaks designer

Tags: c#, reference

I have a user control (section1), that I need to pass reference to my main form (Form1). The problem is whenever I pass the form as a argument to constructor of section1, it breaks the designer and I get an error:

```
 Type 'M.section1' does not have a constructor with parameters of types Form.    

 The variable 's1' is either undeclared or was never assigned.
```

*Form1.Designer.cs*

```
 this.s1 = new M.section1(this); // this is the line that causes the problem
```

*section1.cs* The user control

```
public partial class section1 : UserControl
{
    private Form1 f { get; set; }

    public section1(Form1 frm) // constructor 
    {
         f = frm;
    }
}
```

It's weird that even though when I open Form1 in designer, it gives me the error, it compiles fine and the reference actually works and I can access Form1 from the user control. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: What's the point of having a private auto-property?

Comment: what is "M" in your declaration?

Comment: It is very unclear how you got this code in the designer.cs file, a control requires a parameterless constructor.  *Never* edit the InitializeComponent() method.  You can get the designer to auto-generate code that gives the parent reference, shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12072179/17034).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Designer uses reflection to create instance of your control. Hence you need a default constructor - that's what its looking for.

```
public partial class section1 : UserControl
{
    private Form1 f { get; set; }

    public section1() // designer calls this
    {
        InitializeComponent(); //I hope you haven't forgotten this
    }

    public section1(Form1 frm) : this() //call default from here : at runtime
    {
         f = frm;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you make the call at runtime be different from the call at design time? Do you just overwrite the original UserControl?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I always use is having a default constructor or adding a default `null` value to the `frm` parameter:

```
public section1(Form1 frm = null)
{
    f = frm;
}
```

You might need to add some `null` checks here and there.

Comment: Thanks, I tried both solutions (using default constructor and passing null) and rebuilt the solution, but still the same problem occurs, any suggestions?

Comment: The same exact error in the same place? I like to clean the solution before rebuilding it, in cases like these.

Comment: Maybe close project, delete ".suo" file and bin folders, then reopen and rebuild.