# Winforms add Form to Component via Interface

Tags: c#, winforms, interface, devexpress, components

I have DevExpress XtraForm, which implements a self written Interface. Then i have component, which has an Property from the Type of the Interface. So i thought if i pull the component to the Form, i can set the Form as value for the component Property. But this doesnt work. The Designer doesn't show my Form in the Menu. If i change the PropertyType of my component to XtraForm it works as expected.

1. Winform implements ITest
2. Component got Property from Type ITest
3. Winform add Component
4. In Designer i can see the Property of the component but its not possible to set. Dropdown-Dialog is empty.

Someone can help me?

Comment: The designer uses Reflection to discover things.  It can only find out such things for classes that are actually compiled, so that reflection can work.  Your Form class is not compiled yet, no way for it to discover that it implements ITest.  It can find out things about its base class, as you found out.  Use [this hack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12072179/17034) to let a component discover the form it is hosted on by itself.  Simply assigning the property in the form constructor is the one-liner solution.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks this is helpful. I won't use designer. Doing it in constructor is more efficient. Post as answer and i will accept ;)